# Determining gaps in overlapping time ranges

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of start and end dates for a set of users - let's say during this date range a user is 'on'.

For a given user, the date ranges may overlap with each other. I want to be able to find the gaps between these ranges, i.e. date ranges when a user is NOT 'on'.

This is an example of the source I'm working with:

```
data blocks;
    infile datalines dsd missover;
    input uniq:$1. start_dt:datetime. end_dt:datetime.;
    format start_dt end_dt datetime.;
datalines;
A,01JAN2021:08:00:00,01JAN2021:10:00:00
B,01JAN2021:18:00:00,01JAN2021:20:00:00
B,01JAN2021:09:00:00,01JAN2021:11:00:00
B,02JAN2021:11:00:00,02JAN2021:15:00:00
A,02JAN2021:10:00:00,02JAN2021:12:00:00
B,02JAN2021:10:00:00,02JAN2021:15:00:00
B,03JAN2021:09:00:00,03JAN2021:10:00:00
;;;;
run;
```

I would want the output to be something like this:

```
A   01JAN21:10:00:00    02JAN21:10:00:00
B   01JAN21:11:00:00    01JAN21:18:00:00
B   01JAN21:20:00:00    02JAN21:10:00:00
B   02JAN21:15:00:00    03JAN21:09:00:00
```

I have previously found a solution (I'm afraid I no longer have the link) using SQL, but this joins five instances of the dataset with itself and is unworkable for me, with observations potentially into the tens of millions.

This is that method, which works, but is not practical for my actual use data:

```
proc sql;
    create table gaps_sql as
        select distinct a.uniq
                    ,   a.end_dt as last_end_dt
                    ,   b.start_dt as next_start_dt
        from            blocks a
        inner join      blocks b
        on              a.end_dt < b.start_dt
            and         a.uniq = b.uniq
            and         b.start_dt = (
                            select min(start_dt) 
                            from blocks c
                            where c.start_dt > a.end_dt
                                and c.uniq = b.uniq
                            )
        where           not exists (
                            select  * from blocks d
                            where   d.start_dt < a.end_dt
                                and d.end_dt > a.end_dt
                                and d.uniq = a.uniq
                            )
        order by        a.uniq, a.end_dt
;quit;
```

Is there a way to do this that is more efficient and would work in a reasonable time for many observations? Perhaps a DATA step or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ordered hash to store and sort the datetime ranges.
Iterate over the hash entries to determine and output the gaps.

Example:

```
data have;
infile datalines dsd missover;
input id:$1. start_dt:datetime. end_dt:datetime.;
format start_dt end_dt datetime.;
datalines;
A,01JAN2021:08:00:00,01JAN2021:10:00:00
B,01JAN2021:18:00:00,01JAN2021:20:00:00
B,01JAN2021:09:00:00,01JAN2021:11:00:00
B,02JAN2021:11:00:00,02JAN2021:15:00:00
A,02JAN2021:10:00:00,02JAN2021:12:00:00
B,02JAN2021:10:00:00,02JAN2021:15:00:00
B,03JAN2021:09:00:00,03JAN2021:10:00:00
;

data want(keep=id gap_start gap_end);
  length id $1 start_dt end_dt 8;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash ranges(ordered:'a');
    ranges.defineKey('id', 'start_dt', 'end_dt');
    ranges.defineDone();
    call missing (id, start_dt, end_dt);
  end;

  set have end=done;
  rc = ranges.add();

  if done then do;
    declare hiter i1('ranges');

    do while (i1.next()=0);
      if id ne lag(id) then do;
        right = end_dt;
      end;
      else do;
        if start_dt > right then do;
          * gap;
          gap_start = right;
          gap_end = start_dt;
          output;
          right = end_dt;
        end;
        else do;
          * overlap, possible range extension;
          right = max(right, end_dt);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  format gap: datetime.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It works as expected and is almost instantaneous on just over 1M observations. I obviously need to learn about hashes. Do you have any recommended resources for doing so?

Comment: There are many conference papers on the topic, search at www.lexjansen.com.  A good book for practical applications "Data Management Solutions Using SAS® Hash Table Operations: A Business Intelligence Case Study"